# Adding 2 fields to Log a Call under Activity in Salesforce

Tags: custom-field

We are trying to add two custom fields under the Log a Call widget in the Activity to capture key information. Our SFDC team is saying this is not possible as Activity tab has its limitation and I saw a couple of questions here in this forum where the answers were the same.
Is this possible to add custom fields in the Log a Call widget? If yes, can someone send me reference on how to do it?
Thanks you.
Rob

Answer (score 2):

You can follow these steps. First create the custom field in Activity Object. Then go to **Global Actions** in Setup. Click the *Layout* link against *Log a Call*.

[image]

Edit the Layout.

[image]

You can see the custom field created here. Drag the field to the desired location.

[image]

Now you can see the Custom Field in Log a Call section.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, Saroj! This is awesome! Do you know if we can enable attachment to this Log a Call screen as well?

Comment: Please remember to accept it as answer. It will help others who meet similar questions in this forum. Regarding attaching files you can't do via this screen. This is still in [Idea](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000ZcW9AAK) stage. As a workaround, you can attach a file from the related list of the task after creating the task record from log a call.